# Domino Data Service API Documentation

Tags: json, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

This link to the API documentation is dead >>> 
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html

Anybody have a working link?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't found another link for Data Service documentation but, in case you weren't aware, HCL have other Notes and Domino documentation at https://help.hcltechsw.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s archived at archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20190624013931/http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html.

Answer (score 2):

All the DAS documentation is now available at hcltechsw.com here:

https://ds_infolib.hcltechsw.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api